# Other greedy choices to solve activity selection problem

Tags: algorithms, optimization, greedy-algorithms

I have been studying about [activity-selection-problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_selection_problem) and the solution of greedy choice I came across is to select the activity that finishes in the earliest among the present activities.

But surely there are other greedy choices to solve the problem. The one I have been able to figure out is to select the activity that starts last.

My question is: are there any other greedy choices that can lead to solve activity selection problem? Any formal proof is also appreciated.

Comment: Cf. Borodin's models of priority algorithms.

Comment: Have you tried proving optimality of your criterion?

Comment: Both the approaches work optimally. I could prove them.

Comment: OP means "to select the activity that starts last", moving back in time after that. The usual greedy algorithm on this problem is to select the activity that finishes the earliest, moving ahead in time after that. These two methods are essentially the same as they are symmetric to each other.